# Python Poetry sub package

Tags: python-poetry

I have a certain package containing a couple of "sub packages":

```
package
├── pyproject.toml
│
├── sub_package1
│   └── pyproject.toml
│   └── do_stuff1.py
│  
├── sub_package2
│    └── pyproject.toml
│    └── do_stuff2.py
```

I like to import only sub_package1 instead on installing the entire package.

Is it doable using Poetry? I tried doing so but it looks like without the parent package the subs won't be recognized

Comment: [Check out this Poetry ticket](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2270)